# FileProvider sharing file on Android 11

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm facing a weird issue. I'm running on Samsung Galaxy S20FE Android 11.
I want to open a PDF file from my app so as I've searched around I need to use a fileProvider.
This is how I declared it in the manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<root-path name="root" path="/storage/" />
</paths>
```

The file is located inside the app's directory but on SD and not in internal storage of the device.
I'm calling the function to open PDF file:

```
File file = new File(pdfpath);
Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "package.myapp.provider", file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "No Application Available to View PDF",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

According to anywhere I've searched I don't see what I'm missing. I also tried something for older version that should give UriPermissions to all needed packages:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);


for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | 
         Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

But no matter what I try, I always end up with the same exception:

```
2021-05-25 18:04:03.556 8873-8907/package.myapp E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing android.support.v4.content.FileProvider uri content://package.myapp.provider/root/0A18-B25A/Android/Data/package.myapp/gis/pdf/dragunov.pdf from pid=13365, uid=10104 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

I don't understand why I'm getting permission denied. Also, I've tried setting the XML property to export the FileProvider but I ended up with getting an exception about that the provider can not be exported due to security so I decided not to try and go in that direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "This is the XML file" -- `root-path` is undocumented. "I don't understand why I'm getting permission denied" -- it appears that something is trying to write to the location identified by the `Uri`, but you have only granted `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. If write operations are expected, have you tried adding `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`?

Comment: No, no one is trying to write, I'm trying to share the PDF file from my app to a different app. That different app is just a reader

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried adding it (the write permission) still same issue. Also, I know it's undocumented, I found it some other places on my search. Thing is, the documented path variable all points to directories that are not relevant to me while root-path is the only one that seems to be ok.

Comment: "the documented path variable all points to directories that are not relevant to me" -- then perhaps put your PDF in one of those directories. Or, perhaps write your own `ContentProvider` to serve the PDF. Beyond that, have you tried removing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, to see if that has an impact?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm trying to avoid that as it will break a lot of the app's logic, if I won't find a solution guess I will though. Yes, I've tried removing the ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, still wont change anything. Even if I were to implement my own ContentProvider, I'd still not be able to give it path other than the ones specified no? And even if I could, I'd still end up failing on the URI part as the general fileProvider now providers me with a valid URI, according to the debugger

Comment: "Even if I were to implement my own ContentProvider, I'd still not be able to give it path other than the ones specified no?" -- a custom `ContentProvider` can serve whatever it has access to. `FileProvider` is a subclass of `ContentProvider`, supplied by a Jetpack library, to try to solve a certain common class of problem. Other developers can create their own subclasses of `ContentProvider`, as the developers of `FileProvider` did.

Comment: "I'd still end up failing on the URI part" -- possibly. I do not know exactly what is going wrong here. My point about moving the file or creating your own `ContentProvider` was more a response to "the documented path variable all points to directories that are not relevant to me". Relying on undocumented and unsupported options is risky.

Answer (score 0):

> > `<root-path name="root" path="/storage/" />`

You cannot use root-path anymore on an Android 11 device.

Think it was not even possible since  Android Q.

So FileProvider cannot serve from removable media now adays.

Use your own ContentProvider to do so.

Comment: Well, if I place the file in a directory inside the SD card, but not under android/data this code does work so I wouldn't say it's not working.

Comment: Please give an example of full path. Value of `pdfpath`.

Comment: Full path of the situation I'm facing now which it's not working: /storage/card_id/android/data/app_dir/pdf/pdffile.pdf
Full path of the situation I described and is working:
/storage/card_id/directory/pdffile.pdf

Comment: `<root-path  ` is not usable on Android 11. For no file. Has nothing to do with removable storage. Well... that is my experience untill now... But i do not have that Samsung. Change `path="/storage/" ` to `path="." ` for a test.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try implementing my own FileProvider and see how it goes. As I said though, I was able to open said PDF file when I placed it in a directory inside the SD card.

Comment: I tried implementing my own fileProvider aswell as changing it to "." . same errors for both approaches

Comment: Your own ContentProvider in 30 minutes? Hard to believe. But then... if you want help... post your code.. Start a new topic for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232859/discussion-between-dan-baruch-and-blackapps).